# htaccess - Redirect /something/* to /something

Tags: .htaccess

Examples:

```
/something/foo --> show /something
/something/foo/bar --> show /something
/something/foo/bar/baz --> show /something
```

I'll parse the URL with JS.

Also, in my machine the route is localhost/websites/MyWebsite/something so ideally it should also work for my machine (or if it's not possible, I need to .htaccess one for the server and one for my machine)

Comment: Kindly do share your htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: Hi, sorry I don't have any rules yet

Comment: Sorry but it's encouraged on SO to add basic efforts in htaccess at least basic rules which you tried. Kindly do add after some research and we/I will try to help cheers

Comment: Nevermind I found a solution, don't know if it's the best but at least it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well nobody answered so after a lot of testing this worked for me:

```
RewriteRule ^something/(.+)$ something.php
```

In my case it was a php file